# Javascript: getElementsByClassName: how to get only parents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <img class="item-image" src="${item.getImage()}"/>
    <p>${item.getName()}</p>
</div>
```

and Javascript:

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        addBorder(e.target);

    });
};

function addBorder(item) {
    if (item.tagName = 'DIV') {
        item.style.border = "3px solid red";
    }
}
```

When I click on item, it adds a red border. However if the click happened to touch the image or the paragraph, the red border is drawn around them. I tried to prevent it by adding the if condition inside `addBorder`, but it didn't help. Is there a way to only make the parent div red-bordered, even if the click happened to land inside `p` or `img`?

[image]

Comment: `function addBorder(item) { if (item.closest('.item')) { item.closest('.item').style.border = "3px solid red"; } }` would be a far better version of `addBorder`, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

Because `item.tagName = 'DIV'` means: assigning `DIV` to `item.tagName`. So you just need to replace `item.tagName = 'DIV'` with `item.tagName === 'DIV'` for comparing.

```
if (item.tagName === 'DIV') {
    item.style.border = "3px solid red";
}
```